# Computing the expected value $E[X(X+5)]$

Tags: probability

I know $  E[XY] = \int \int x y f(x,y) dx dy $   where $f(x,y) = f(x)f(y)$

But I am not entirely sure how to compute $E[X(X+5)]$.

Is it $\int f(x)(5 + \int f(x) dx) dx$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\mathbb{E}[X(X+5)]= \mathbb{E}[X^2+5X] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (x^2+5x)f_X(x)dx$$

Also note that $f(x,y)$ is equal to $f(x)f(y)$ when $x$ and $y$ are independent.

Comment: ah wow i thought random variables could not be distributed

Comment: Random variables are functions, they can be manipulated in the usual way. Anyway, we don't need to distribute, though we can. The expectation is $\int_{-\infty}^\infty x(x+5)f(x)\,dx$.

Comment: f_x(x) means the differential of f(x)?

Comment: @George No it is the same $f(x)$ : probability distribution function of random variable $X$ is being written as $f_X(x)$

Comment: ah so it doesn't really carry any meaning if the random variable was A it would have been $f_A(x)$, right? thanks.

Comment: @George Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have only one random variable $X$ here you can compute $\mathbb{E}(X(X+5))$ simply as $$\mathbb{E}(X(X+5))=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(x+5)f_X(x) \ dx$$